# ScalaTest - java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, scalatest

I'm getting **IncompatibleClassChangeError** when run test as ScalaTest from eclipse, the flowing is the full stack trace of the errors. Can anyone give me some advise? Thanks in advance!

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort. This may have been caused by a problematic custom reporter.
    java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$35.apply(Runner.scala:2438)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$35.apply(Runner.scala:2436)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$filter$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:264)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.filter(TraversableLike.scala:263)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.filter(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:2436)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1044)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1043)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:2722)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1043)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.main(Runner.scala:860)
        at org.scalatest.tools.Runner.main(Runner.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher$.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala:20)
        at scala.tools.eclipse.scalatest.launching.ScalaTestLauncher.main(ScalaTestLauncher.scala)
```

Jar dependency and maven plugins are like below:

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Source code would be helpful.

Comment: As well as versions of dependencies and Scala.

Comment: Hi @kukido, Source code is just a simple assertion, nothing special. For the dependency, is anything wrong?

Comment: Hi @alexey-romanov, any problem with the dependency?

Comment: I don't see any immediate problems.

Comment: I have the same error, appeared when I moved project from Scala 2.11.7 to 2.11.8.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class with ScalaCheck and ScalaTest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35312410/java-lang-incompatibleclasschangeerror-implementing-class-with-scalacheck-and-s)

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. The issue was that the test class had the same name as the tested file, and was in the same package. If that's your case, a simple rename would be enough.

Hope it helps someone!